# how to include multiple docx template data into single template using jinj2 tags

Tags: python, jinja2, python-docx

I would like to include the child docx template into master docx template using the jinja2 tags

I have two templates one is **main.docx** and the other is **child.docx
when I am using this jinja2 tag in the master template

`{% include "child.docx" %}`

The child template should be included into the master template but i am getting the errors
`File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code`
`TypeError: no loader for this environment specified`

I am doing this docx templating using docxtpl module.
Please suggest

Comment: Please read [mcve]